# Update all dictionary.keys() of d2 with dictionary.keys() of d1

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries, d1 and d2: how do I update all the keys() of d2 with the keys() of d1?

d1:

```
{
    'btn-orange__p-3': None, 
    'btn-red__btn-transparent_text-underline': None,
    'quadruple__border_border-primary': None
}
```

d2:

```
{
    'btn-orange': '<a class="btn btn-warning p-3" href="#" role="button">[]</a>', 
    'btn-red': '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-transparent text-underline" href="#" role="button">[]</a>', 
    'quadruple': '<div class="col-lg-3 border border-primary">\n{}\n</div>'
}
```

Desired:

d2:

```
{
    'btn-orange__p-3': '<a class="btn btn-warning p-3" href="#" role="button">[]</a>',
    'btn-red__btn-transparent_text-underline': '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-transparent text-underline" href="#" role="button">[]</a>',
    'quadruple__border_border-primary': '<div class="col-lg-3 border border-primary">\n{}\n</div>'
}
```

I'm sure it's a simple `for k, v in dict` solution or `{ k: v for k, v in dict.items() }` dict comprehension but i'm bumping my head

Comment: What do you mean by "update all the keys"? What's the rule for how they match up?

Comment: Do all of your keys follow the pattern: `sameasd2__otherstuff`?

Comment: If they do follow this pattern, try `{k: d2.get(k.split('__')[0], None) for k in d1.keys()}`

Comment: The relationship is that dict1 is appended from dict2 followed by a "__"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at what you want here:

- The `d1` keys all look like `prefix__suffix` (with at least one underscore after the prefix, not exactly one).
- For each `d2` key, if it's equal to the `prefix` of any `d1` key, replace it with that key.

  - If it's a prefix of multiple `d1` keys, we can pick one arbitrarily.
  - If it's not a prefix of any `d1` key, just leave it alone.

If this is what you want, the first thing to do is create a key-mapping dict out of the `d1.keys()`:

```
keymap = {key.partition('_')[0]: key for key in d1}
```

And now, we can apply that to the keys in d2:

```
d3 = {keymap.get(key, key): value for key, value in d2.items()}
```

---

If what you want is a minor variation on my guess—e.g., if the prefix has to be followed by exactly two underscores rather than at least one—it should be obvious how to adapt it.

But if it's something more different… well, you have to be able to define your rule in English before you can code it in Python. But it may well be something that can't be handled by a dict at all.

For example, if the rule is "if the d2 key is a substring of any d1 key, which could be in any format…" then you're either going to need to build a more complex text-searching data structure, or do a linear search for each key:

```
def mapkey(key):
    for k in d1:
        if key in k: return k
    return key
d3 = {mapkey(key): value for key, value in d2.items()}
```

(This is obviously a bit more complicated, and a lot less efficient.)

---

Also, if your rule has anything to do with the ordering of the dicts, you should probably take a step back and rethink what you're doing. Dictionaries are inherently unordered. In some Python interpreters (CPython 3.6+, PyPy 2.7 and 3.3+ except for the very early PyPy versions of those Python versions, etc.), dicts do happen to maintain their original creation/insertion order if you stay within certain constraints, but is that really something you want to rely on? If ordering matters, use an `OrderedDict`, or a `list`, or some other type that's inherently ordered instead of inherently arbitrary but sometimes predictable.

Comment: Thanks man and I appreciate the additional info and insight, fantastic